# Ruby - get bit range from variable

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

I have a variable and want to take a range of bits from that variable.  I want the CLEANEST way to do this.

If `x = 19767` and I want bit3 - bit8 (starting from the right):
`100110100110111` is `19767` in binary.
I want the part in parenthesis `100110(100110)111` so the answer is 38.

What is the simplest/cleanest/most-elegant way to implement the following function with Ruby?

```
bit_range(orig_num, first_bit, last_bit)
```

PS. Bonus points for answers that are computationally less intensive.

Comment: So you don't want to learn binary and use ANDs and SHIFTs like us veterans? Huh. Kids these days. :-)

Comment: no no... bring on the binary! I'm all about it.

Comment: You should accept @DigitalRoss's answer then as he's showing both a String based solution, along with pure bit twiddling. Don't reject using `to_s(2)` though, it can short-circuit a lot of messy shifting and ANDing.

Comment: I'll accept an answer, don't worry.  I'm not a stack-overflow slacker.  I'm confused about your second sentance, Digital Ross's second answer has no to_s(2) and it is not messy.

Comment: Comments to @texasbruce's answer wanted a non-`to_s(2)` solution. There's a lot to be said for using `to_s(2)` string manipulation, though it gives up a little speed as it can greatly simply the twiddling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
19767.to_s(2)[-9..-4].to_i(2)
```

or

```
19767 >> 3 & 0x3f
```

*Update:*

Soup-to-nuts (why do people say that, anyway?) ...

```
class Fixnum
  def bit_range low, high
    len = high - low + 1
    self >> low & ~(-1 >> len << len)
  end
end

p 19767.bit_range(3, 8)
```

Comment: i like the second one because it doesn't require string conversion, but is there a way to make it more general, so I could input any starting bit and any ending bit

Comment: Sure there's ways to do it, but we expect you to figure that sort of thing out. It's simply substituting  variables for  values you've calculated. Think of what `0x3f` looks in binary, along with what `>> 3` is doing.

Comment: I guess I could substitute 0x3f with 2^(high_bit)-1 ??

Comment: @Selah .. well, the Tin Man is right, but I had the idea of monkey-patching Fixnum and could not resist showing you the whole answer. I hope you like it.   BTW, I answered the Q as asked, but I would suggest reversing the order of `low, high` to `high, low`.

Comment: Adding `bit_range` strikes a nice balance with readability and speed. Well done, as usual. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
orig_num.to_s(2)[(-last_bit-1)..(-first_bit-1)].to_i(2)
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I wonder if there is a clean way to do this task without converting to a string and back...

Comment: @GregoryBrown you cant really do bitwise shift because selecting a range requires shifting both right and left, and the boundary for shifting left in Ruby is .. Eh unknown.

Comment: Good point. I was sort of hoping that because you can do `original_num[index]`, that original_num[start..end] would work, but unfortunately that's not supported ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just to show the speeds of the suggested answers:

```
require 'benchmark'

ORIG_NUMBER = 19767

def f(x,i,j)
  b = x.to_s(2)
  n = b.size
  b[(n-j-1)...(n-i)].to_i(2)
end

class Fixnum
  def bit_range low, high
    len = high - low + 1
    self >> low & ~(-1 >> len << len)
  end

  def slice(range_or_start, length = nil)
    if length
      start = range_or_start
    else
      range = range_or_start
      start = range.begin
      length = range.count
    end

    mask = 2 ** length - 1

    self >> start & mask
  end
end

def p n
  puts "0b#{n.to_s(2)}"; n
end

n = 1_000_000
puts "Using #{ n } loops in Ruby #{ RUBY_VERSION }."
Benchmark.bm(21) do |b|
  b.report('texasbruce') { n.times { ORIG_NUMBER.to_s(2)[(-8 - 1)..(-3 - 1)].to_i(2) } }
  b.report('DigitalRoss string') { n.times { ORIG_NUMBER.to_s(2)[-9..-4].to_i(2) } }
  b.report('DigitalRoss binary') { n.times { ORIG_NUMBER >> 3 & 0x3f } }
  b.report('DigitalRoss bit_range') { n.times { 19767.bit_range(3, 8) } }
  b.report('Philip') { n.times { f(ORIG_NUMBER, 3, 8) } }
  b.report('Semyon Perepelitsa') { n.times { ORIG_NUMBER.slice(3..8) } }
end
```

And the output:

```
Using 1000000 loops in Ruby 1.9.3.
                            user     system      total        real
texasbruce              1.240000   0.010000   1.250000 (  1.243709)
DigitalRoss string      1.000000   0.000000   1.000000 (  1.006843)
DigitalRoss binary      0.260000   0.000000   0.260000 (  0.262319)
DigitalRoss bit_range   0.840000   0.000000   0.840000 (  0.858603)
Philip                  1.520000   0.000000   1.520000 (  1.543751)
Semyon Perepelitsa      1.150000   0.010000   1.160000 (  1.155422)
```

That's on my old MacBook Pro. Your mileage might vary.

Comment: Nice :-) You should add an example with length too: ORIG_NUMBER.slice(3, 6)

Comment: No DigitalRose 's solutions does not contain variables. Its all constants so surly its faster.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how this could be done using pure number operations:

```
class Fixnum
  def slice(range_or_start, length = nil)
    if length
      start = range_or_start
    else
      range = range_or_start
      start = range.begin
      length = range.count
    end

    mask = 2 ** length - 1

    self >> start & mask
  end
end

def p n
  puts "0b#{n.to_s(2)}"; n
end

p 0b100110100110111.slice(3..8) # 0b100110
p 0b100110100110111.slice(3, 6) # 0b100110
```

Comment: Please don't edit my answer with the results of running the benchmark for your code on your machine. Machines vary in speed, so if you feel your algorithm wasn't running at its full speed feel free to copy the benchmark code, run it on your machine, and put the full results into your answer. Doing otherwise could result in misleading values.

Comment: I have copied the full benchmark results of course. From your comment I thought you were fine with me running the new benchmark on my machine.

Comment: I'm fine with you running it, just don't modify the results I show. You could add your results to your answer, or have appended them to mine. Overwriting mine is different.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your "beat you to it". The point of my solution is not in speed, but I thought your answer might be better with a second usage. Anyway, I'm leaving that up to you.

Comment: thanks semyon, this answer is good, wish I could check two answers

Answer (score 1):

Makes sense to define a function for that:

```
def f(x,i,j)
  b = x.to_s(2)
  n = b.size
  b[(n-j-1)...(n-i)].to_i(2)
end

puts f(19767, 3, 8) # => 38
```

Comment: nice, thanks for actually defining a function.  is there a way to do it without converting to strings though??

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the idea from DigitalRoss - instead of taking two arguments, you can pass a range:

```
class Fixnum
  def bit_range range
    len = range.last - range.first + 1
    self >> range.first & ~(-1 >> len << len)
  end
end

19767.bit_range 3..8
```